# Is there a shareware making app for Objective-C Desktop Mac apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, paypal

I was wondering if there were any libraries out there to allow Mac desktop developers on Objective-C to create shareware applications, similar to sharify for Air. Perhaps through use of Paypal etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a prebuilt library that allows you to charge money for your app and so on, then the answer is "yes", with the caveat that "they're all kinda mediocre".

Here are the ones I know about:

1. [PotionStore](http://www.potionfactory.com/potionstore) (ruby webstore and cocoa framework to interact with it)
2. [eSellerate](http://www.esellerate.net/)
3. [AquaticPrime](http://aquaticmac.com/)
4. [Golden Braeburn](http://golden-braeburn.com/)
5. [Kagi](http://www.kagi.com/KRM/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but [Kagi](http://www.kagi.com/kagisolutions/software.php?page=krm) has always supported mac shareware.  You can also use WebKit to display a PayPal page directly in you app.

Comment: I would highly recommend against showing a PayPal page in an embedded WebView. You're much better off just opening the page in a browser. From a user's perspective there is zero level of trust in your app, it could be doing anything with the user's PayPal details. Much better to hand it off to the browser which the user is familiar with.

Comment: There is a trust issue with any built in payment option.  And really there is a trust issue with any web page you send the user to, even if you use their browser.  While users may feel more trusting of some options over others, there is little actual difference in security unless they type in a URL to a site they know and trust without ever having launched the program they are buying.